# Merge two files with the latest updated record

Tags: awk

I have two text files A.txt & AA.txt,both having the same header
I need to create a file C by merging these two. If the file contains same record with some change in the update date or created date then it should take only the recent updated record.

I used

```
awk -F"|" '!a[$1]++' /export/home/Vip/A* > C.txt
```

To merge files starting with A. 
How can i get the latest Updated Record.

If 5th Column is update_date. What should i do to get the recently Updated record

Comment: Some sample input data from both files and your desired output would help in getting clear and working answers.

Answer (score 1):

The following merges a set of files such that if the value of `$1` is the same in some or all of the files, it will choose the record with the largest value of `$5`:

```
 awk -f a.awk firstRun=1 file1 file2 firstRun=0 file1 file2
```

where `a.awk` is:

```
BEGIN {FS="|"}
firstRun {
    a[$1]++
    if (a[$1]==1) {
        c[$1]=$5; b[$1]=FILENAME
    }
    else {
        if ($5> c[$1])
            b[$1]=FILENAME
    }
    next
}
b[$1]==FILENAME
```

For sample files:

```
$ cat file1
1|2|3|4|5
6|7|8|9|10
11|12|13|14|15

$ cat file2
1|2|3|4|6
21|22|23|24|25
11|12|13|14|9
```

it gives output:

```
6|7|8|9|10
11|12|13|14|15
1|2|3|4|6
21|22|23|24|25
```